# How to apply mean/average pooling over the batch size to get a single output for the whole batch in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

For eg.- the input with dimensions [10,1,224,224] is required to be reduced to [1,1,224,224] where [samples,channels,rows,columns] is the convention for the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Then your problem is badly formuled, consider using [10,1,224,224] as input_shape and make batches of such tensors. Then use Averagepooling3D, see doc [here](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#averagepooling3d).
You won't be able to make operations on batches with the usual layers, except maybe if you build your own custom layer : see [here](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/).